# Random values to string on each instance in Geometry Nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I have a displaced grid 200x200 points. Then I have the same grid but narrowed selection on which I instance the lines And the strings.

[image: render view]
**My question is... Is there any possibility to get different values (based on whatever) in the instanced strings?** Because the Value to string node doesn't support field input.

[image]

Where in the node tree should I integrate the random value to the string? Is it possible? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The ID input for the Random Value is the one to be used for getting different values.

Comment: The seed part is easily solved, the problem is there is no way to instance a customizable number of strings with customizable values in a single node tree (String to Curves doesn't support fields neither does Value to String) I think it will not be possible until string attributes are supported natively.

Comment: tried a dumb workaround for this by stacking digits, made all 10 digits individual objects, but also had to instance them 4 times for each location, otherwise the random pick would not work right... [here the blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/labfm6clubnp73k/digits.blend?dl=1)

Comment: @calambre great idea!

Comment: thanks @3Dhedgehog! but it's workaround, I'm sure they will add a way to do it

Comment: https://youtu.be/_W47HfoeFsg I’ve layed out a method to visualize numerical attributes in 3D view. If I knew a shorter way of explaining it here, I would. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can input bunch of any geometry elements into "Instance On Points" node via "Geometry To Instance" node.

**All setup:**

[image]

You can add hundreeds "text" groups to this node setup. If you do so, the output numbers will be very random. The only problem is that you should manually create all the list.

**Inside "Text" Group:**

[image]

Comment: That is exactly what I did after posting the question lol... Its not Ideal, but it will do the trick. I hope there will be more options for strings in the future. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Another workaround is to use SVerchok nodes for this case. SVerchok also able to transfer custom value for Geometry Nodes.

I uploaded a video on this.

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the highest currently supported Blender version in conjunction with Sverchock Nodes?

Answer (score 1):

Node Group of an Attribute Visualizer

This is quite doable with geometry nodes, just not as easy. I have developed a method to visualize numeric attributes in the 3D view.

Basically, it takes an arbitrary number, calculates the length of its digits, duplicates the input geometry points as many times as there are digits, and then creates instances of text curves to those duplicated points. Based on the indices of the duplicated points and the input number, it selects the correct curve number from the numbers 0-9.

I know this sounds very lengthy, but here I have posted a screenshot of my node tree. If I knew how to explain it in a shorter way, I would do it here. For a full explanation of why this works, check out my video tutorial.

https://youtu.be/_W47HfoeFsg

P.S. If you add a *Mesh to Points* node before you feed the geometry into this node group, and change the domain type to *Faces" or *Edges*, you can also visualize their attributes. I hope this helps you.

[image: Node Group of an Attribute Visualizer]

Answer (score 0):

One can pass a string of all the digits to the `String to Curves` node and sample single characters by checking the `Pick Instance` box of the `Instance on Points` node as shown in the image below.

You will still have to manually assemble larger numbers, but it is a neater solution.

[image: node setup digit counter]