# GeoNodes - Random numbers on points of a grid

Tags: geometry-nodes, random

I would like to create a grid in Geometry Nodes and add random numbers to its points.
Sounds so easy... I am a beginner and just cannot figure out how... could you please advise?
[image: How to add random number?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: [Random values to string on each instance in Geometry Nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254588/)

I think geometry nodes needs an update that will allow this better.

Comment: thank you very much for your help! Now I understand from the [explanation you quoted](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254588/random-values-to-string-on-each-instance-in-geometry-nodes) that once I "invoke" `Instance on points`, it will not get back to the `String to curves` for eachpoints - of course :).

In case `Instance on points` receives one instance, that will be put on every relevant points. In case I can give it several instances, I can use "pick instance".

My concept above was wrong - and now I feel further away from the solution. :)